# Error #1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row

Tags: mysql, sql

each time i tried to run this query it gives this error 
**1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row**

```
SELECT(SELECT numbers.phone FROM numbers WHERE numbers.filename = 'Jan-2013') AS Jan2013,
(SELECT numbers.phone FROM numbers WHERE numbers.filename = 'Dec-2012') AS Dec2012
```

actually i don't know where is the problem .
and this is the table design .

```
CREATE TABLE `numbers` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `phone` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `phonecalls` int(3) NOT NULL,
  `duration` float NOT NULL,
  `cost` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `city` varchar(255) default NULL,
  `category` varchar(255) default NULL,
  `website` varchar(255) default NULL,
  `reported` int(1) NOT NULL default '0',
  `filename` varchar(255) default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=12065 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: This mean that `SELECT numbers.phone FROM numbers WHERE numbers.filename = 'Jan-2013'` or `SELECT numbers.phone FROM numbers WHERE numbers.filename = 'Dec-2012'` returns more than 1 row

Comment: I recommend you run both of your `subSELECTs` and see which one returns  multiple values. Then try to limit that query to 1 row.

Comment: Also, please tell us what you're trying to do, maybe there's a simpler way.

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu i believe those 2 queries return more than 1 row .
what i need to perform is to get each result as a column which i can loops through it in PHP .
simply getting all phone numbers for Jan as column Jan and so on .
didn't know that subSelects must return only 1 row

Comment: Actually you haven't designed your query correct. I don't think this syntax will ever work. What you are searching for is done differently. You should post what you are trying to do in your question.

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu Thx anyway i am not so good in SQL i will do it through PHP codes

Comment: Can you post desired output from your query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that you're after a query like this

```
SELECT filename, phone
  FROM numbers
 WHERE filename IN ('Dec-2012', 'Jan-2013')
 ORDER BY filename, phone
```

Sample output:

```
| FILENAME |       PHONE |
--------------------------
| Dec-2012 | 120-1111532 |
| Dec-2012 | 123-1111111 |
...
| Jan-2013 | 111-1116677 |
| Jan-2013 | 133-1111234 |
...
```

It will give you a properly ordered resultset with data that you need in one go which you can easily iterate over in php.

**Another approach** is to use `GROUP_CONCAT` to pack all phones per filename in a delimited string which you can easily explode in php while you iterate over the resultset

```
SELECT filename, GROUP_CONCAT(phone ORDER BY phone) phones
  FROM numbers
 WHERE filename IN ('Dec-2012', 'Jan-2013')
 GROUP BY filename
```

Sample output:

```
| FILENAME |                                                                  PHONES |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Dec-2012 | 120-1111532,123-1111111,133-1111144                                     |
| Jan-2013 | 111-1116677,133-1111234,156-9851115,171-1274116,172-1111089,199-6571114 |
```

---

**Now you definitely don't want** to get phone numbers for each filename in separate columns. You can technically do that with a query like this

```
SELECT rnum, 
       MIN(CASE WHEN filename = 'Dec-2012' THEN phone END) `Dec-2012`,
       MIN(CASE WHEN filename = 'Jan-2013' THEN phone END) `Jan-2013`
  FROM
(
  SELECT n.*, IF(@g = filename, @n := @n + 1, @n := 1) rnum, @g := filename
    FROM numbers n, (SELECT @n := 1) i
   WHERE filename IN ('Dec-2012', 'Jan-2013')
) q
 GROUP BY rnum
```

but it makes no sense, because you don't have any common column you can group your data on other than a row number.

Your resultset will look something like this

```
| RNUM |    DEC-2012 |    JAN-2013 |
------------------------------------
|    1 | 123-1111111 | 111-1116677 |
|    2 | 120-1111532 | 172-1111089 |
|    3 | 133-1111144 | 133-1111234 |
|    4 |      (null) | 199-6571114 |
|    5 |      (null) | 156-9851115 |
...
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8a658/7)** demo

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you want a single result for each query or all results for each query, but if you want all results, here's one method (although it's not the fastest way because you're querying the same table twice, but it should at least get you your results):

```
SELECT n1.phone as Jan2013, n2.phone AS Dec2012
FROM numbers AS n1, numbers AS n2
WHERE n1.filename = 'Jan-2013'
AND n2.filename = 'Dec-2012'
```

If you just want a single result, you should be able to use the code you have already, except you'll have to specify something that tells the subquery to only return one result (such as `MAX()` or `MIN()`):

```
SELECT
(SELECT MAX(numbers.phone) FROM numbers WHERE numbers.filename = 'Jan-2013') AS Jan2013,
(SELECT MIN(numbers.phone) FROM numbers WHERE numbers.filename = 'Dec-2012') AS Dec2012
```

Hope that helps... :)